# Filter search results sphinx

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I have setup sphinx and can perform searches using the php api. But I have two questions.

1. In this test database I have a number of products which each have a category id. How would I go about creating a filtering function so that a user after a search can retrieve results ONLY from a specific category. Thats is, first i search for car and get 10 matches, then I choose the category Ford and only get 3 matches, ie the cars with category Ford.
2. I'm a little confused to wheter sphinx searches my index or search the db direcly. I thought it searched the index, but then I changed a text in the db and made a search wihout reindexing, and the changes I made to the text showed up in the result.

All help much appreciated, as allways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a filter, you must add the attribute to your data source (don't forget to select it in your SQL query  `SELECT category_id, ...`):

```
sql_attr_uint = category_id
```

Then you'll be able to add a filter from your PHP code:

```
$s->SetFilter('category_id', array(43));
```

For your second question, you need to run the indexer to update the data.

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I tried the filtering function and it works fine. However, I'm still confused about the indexing. I changed a text in the db now WITHOUT reindexing, and the change came up when I searched. Is this not supposed to be?

Comment: @user1009453 So you mean you added a new keyword, searched for that keyword, and it was returned in the results? Without running `indexer` first?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I did not understand the index a first. The ROW with the changed content did show up, but the new content did not return any ROW when searched for. Thank's again!